# for loop through array and bind class to element class attribute in vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, string-interpolation, v-for

I am trying to bind classnames into the class attribute with vuejs looping through an array like this:

Here I pass the method call in a :class="paymentTypeClass(value)" to bind to the vue template like so:

```
<li v-for="card in paymentType" class="o-pf-list__item" :class="paymentTypeClass(value)">
  {{ card }}
</li>

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  paymentType: ['paymentType1', 'paymentType2', 'paymentType3', 'paymentType4', 'paymentType5']
  },
  methods: {
    functionName: function(value) {
      var i = 0;

      for (i in this.paymentType) {

        value = 'o-pf-list__item--' + this.paymentType[i];

      }
      return value + ' pull-left';
    }
  }
});
```

The result is that it only prints out the last index value in the array so it is actually overwriting. Why is this? Please help.

Logs in the console:

```
o-pf-list__item--bitcoin
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--credit
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--debitcard
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--eft
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--masterpass
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--bitcoin
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--credit
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--debitcard
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--eft
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--masterpass
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--bitcoin
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--credit
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--debitcard
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--eft
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--masterpass
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--bitcoin
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--credit
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--debitcard
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--eft
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--masterpass
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--bitcoin
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--credit
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--debitcard
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--eft
app.js:51663 o-pf-list__item--masterpass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing.

What does `paymentTypeClass` look like? It looks like you want all the classes on the element based on your logic? If so you can do like:

```
paymentTypeClasses () {
  const classes = this.paymentType.map(type => 'o-pf-list__item--' + type)
  classes.push('pull-left')
  return classes
}
```

Then do

```
:class="paymentTypeClasses()"
```

or

```
:class="[paymentTypeClasses()]
```

(easier to add more classes later)

Comment: Hi. It should only print one class on the element class attribute. Will give the code now

Comment: The end result should look something like this if the array has 5 values then:                                                             
<li class="o-pf-list__item o-pf-list__item--bitcoin pull-left"> bitcoin</li> repeated with different class binding values from the array

Comment: Fixed it. I just removed the entire function and added this:                      
<li v-for="card in paymentType" class="o-pf-list__item" :class="'o-pf-list__item--' + card + ' pull-left'"></li>