# Vue-agile not working with v-for

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-for

I am working with VueJS2 and Laravel.
Using **vue-agile** for sliding some images and texts.

When I try to add **v-for** for sliding all the posts I get error *"TypeError: Cannot read property '***style***' of undefined"*

Here is the code:

```
<agile :arrows="false" :speed="750" :timing="'linear'" :fade="true" :autoplay="true" :autoplaySpeed="5000" :pauseOnHover="true" :dots="false">  
            <div :class="['testimonial slide slide--' + post.id]"  v-for="post in posts">
                <img :src="`/images/${post.image}`" v-if="post.image">
                <p>{{post.text}}</p>
                <strong>{{post.author}}</strong><br>
            </div>
        </agile>
```

Where is my mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: that :class syntax catches my eyes as being the culprit `:class="['testimonial slide slide--' + post.id]"` look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163329/for-loop-through-array-and-bind-class-to-element-class-attribute-in-vuejs

Comment: Thank you @BabakBandpey, I have tried this example but still the same. The classes are actually adding but still have the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Comment: could you please post some of your script too. Because the error is probably in the script.

Comment: @BabakBandpey This is the part where I include vue-agile:
`import Vue from 'vue'
    import AnimateNumber from '../../components/AnimateNumber.vue'
    import VueAgile from 'vue-agile'
 Vue.use(VueAgile)
    Vue.component('animated-number', AnimateNumber)
 import { get } from '../../helpers/api'
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
    show: false,
    showText: 'View more categories',
    campaigns: [],
    posts: [],
    categories: [],
   }
  }...`

Comment: This error refers to usage of an `object.style` and it says that the `Object` is not defined and I can not see that you have any reference to this unknown `Object` in your component definition. So the question is that if there is a some sort of configuration which has been left out or there are errors in the code in some other components.